# Svelte Conditionally apply on:click event

Tags: svelte

I have a use case when I need a regular button that has an `on:click` event handler or an actual submit button. Depending on criteria, I want a user to click a button to take them to another state of a multipage component (think wizard here) or to stop immediately and submit the form as it stands.

Here's an example of how I want to solve this:

```html
<Button {...props} on:click><slot name="button-label">Submit</slot></Button>
```

The props could receive `type: 'submit'` but it seems that the `on:click` is overriding the submission functionality.

My solution (which works) is doing something like this:

```html
{#if type === 'button'}
  <Button {...props} on:click><slot name="button-label">Submit</slot></Button>
{:else}
  <!-- Removing the on:click allows the button to submit properly -->    
  <Button {...props}><slot name="button-label">Submit</slot></Button>
{/if}
```

It would be nice to be able to use one `Button` component and have an optional `on:click` based on a conditional much like this:

```html
<div class:optional-css-class={someCondition}`>
  Blah blah
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This does not make sense. Where is `Button` from/what is its code?

Comment: Also, show more code, `on:click` just forwards the event, if you have a Wizard, how do you perform the page change?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{...props}` with the individual props for your element. In your `<Button>` component, you could do this;

```
<!-----Button.svelte---->
<script>
import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte'
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>
<button type={$$restProps.type} class={$$restProps.class}
on:click={()=>{
  dispatch('click',{})
}}
>
  <slot/>   
</button>
```

When using your Button component; Indicate the button type (could be; 'submit', 'button', 'reset'), like this;

```
<!-------Using Button Component-------->
<Button class='btn' type='submit' on:click={()=>{}}>
Submit Button
</Button>
```